# как развернуть сокращённую запись комманд на Python

Tags: python

есть вот такой код на питоне

```py
dict = defaultdict(set)

idx = 'one'
val = 'первый'
dict[idx].add(val)
idx = 'two'
val = 'второй'
dict[idx].add(val)
idx = 'three'
val = 'третий'
dict[idx].add(val)
val = 'четвёртый'
dict[idx].add(val)
idx = 'four'
val = 'пятый'
dict[idx].add(val)
idx = 'five'
val = 'шестой'
dict[idx].add(val)
val = 'седьмой'
dict[idx].add(val)
idx = 'six'
val = 'восьмой'
dict[idx].add(val)

n = sum((len(val) > 1) for idx, val in dict.items())
```

подскажите как разложить последнюю строку, что бы получился отдельно цикл в котором что то по условию суммируется
ни как не могу найти объяснения как такое можно сделать

Comment: А чем не понравилась "прямая" инициализация объекта в одну строчку?  `dct = defaultdict(set, one={'первый'}, two={'второй'}, three={'третий', 'четвёртый'})`  Кстати, при такой инициализации можно и обычный словарь использовать, вероятно (не знаю остальных задач алгоритма).

Comment: надо что бы было всё упрощено до невозможности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Инициализируем нашу переменную

```
n = 0
```

2. Переписываем наш *итератор*:

```
for idx, val in dict.items():
```

3. Переписываем *тело* цикла:

```
n += len(val)>1
```

4. Соединяем

```
n = 0
for idx, val in dict.items():
    n += len(val)>1
```

---

Дополнение:

1. Вместо `idx, val in dict.items()` тут следует написать `val in dict.values()`
2. Не стоит называть переменные зарезервированными словами (`dict`, `list`, `set`, ...)

Comment: по переменным, согласен немного не правильно написал
и Спасибо - сработало!